# ¿Cómo lanzo un Update a una base de datos Firebase independiente del dispositivo?

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, flutter, realtime-database

Tengo una base de datos (RealTime) en Firebase con un campo "Tiempo" que es un Int que indica una cantidad de segundos. En mi proyecto Flutter me gustaría que una vez el usuario lo indique, este campo tiempo decrezca en 1 cada segundo que pasa hasta llegar a 0, independientemente de si el usuario cierra la aplicación o se apaga su movil. Estoy perdido y no se como realizar una operación así. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que es imposible hacer eso desde Firebase.

Comment: Podrás comentar el motivo para crear algo así? Mientras mas info tengamos, va a ser mas fácil ayudarte :)